# Loop on array of arrays in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

MAP es6 doesn't work with array of arrays in react, Data:

```
{
"skills": [{
    "field": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": {
            "en": "Web Developer"
        }
    },
    "skills": [{
        "id": 2,
        "name": {
            "en": "Blog"
        }
    }]
}, {
    "field": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": {
            "en": "UI/ UX Designer"
        }
    },

    "skills": [ {
        "id": 4,
        "name": {
            "en": "Web Interface"
        }
    }]
}]
```

}

so in my render of jsx I do:

```
{item.skills.map(item => 
    <p>{item.skills.name}</p>
)}
```

Comment: This object have errors

Comment: Seems, your `item` JSON is having some errors, Try validating the same in `jsonlint.com`

Comment: Your JSON object is not valid. You can use http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ to check validity.

Comment: u are using `item.project.title`, in json u pasted, project and title keys are not present.

Comment: @MayankShukla fixed

Comment: Are you trying to get `"name"` property from object within `"skills"` array or `"field"` object?

Comment: @JessicaRobertson issue is , `this.skills` inside map is again an array.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is `this.skills` inside map is again an `array`, and name is an `object`, first you need to change the `JSON` structure, and to access the name you need to use `name.en`, check this:

```js
let data = {
    "skills": [{
        "field": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": {
                "en": "Web Developer"
            }
        },
        "skills": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": {
                "en": "Blog"
            }
        }
    },{
        "field": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": {
                "en": "UI/ UX Designer"
            }
        },

        "skills": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": {
                "en": "Web Interface"
            }
        }
    }]
}

data.skills.map((item)=>{
     console.log(item.skills.name.en);
})
```

If you defined `skills` inside the `skills` as an `array` and it will contain only one item, then you need to access the name like this:

`item.skills[0].name.en`

Otherwise you need to run a `map` again to access the name. like this:

```
data.skills.map((item)=>{
     item.skills.map((el)=>{
         console.log(el.name.en);
     });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `skills[n].skills` is array. And you need change the structure or execute `.map` again into your first `map` method. Like this:

```
{item.skills.map(item => 
    item.skills.map(skill => 
    <p>{skill.name[en]}</p>
    )
)}
```